# Retain 2 decimal points on float when converting to string delphi

Tags: string, delphi, decimal

I'm adding lines to a memo box from a sql query dataset. The data is being added using the `memo1.lines.add` function looping through the dataset

```
memo1.Clear;
frmMain.Query2.Open;
try
  while not frmMain.Query2.Eof do
  begin
    memo1.Lines.Add(frmMain.Query2.FieldByName('mass').AsString);
    frmMain.Query2.Next;
  end;
finally
  frmMain.Query2.Close;
end;
```

Everething from this point is working fine, the only problem is that because the data is being converted into string format is loses the trailing 0 .ie

```
Float value = 40.50  String Value = 40.5 .
Float value = 42.40  String Value = 42.4 .
Float value = 40.53  String Value = 40.53 .
```

Is there any way this could be rectified? FormatFloat doesn't want to format it because it's not a float anymore. StrtoInt doesn't work because of the 3 sting values in the memobox.

Comment: Read the value as a float and format it how you please. In other words, take control of the conversion to string.

Comment: Thanks , working 100%

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using `AsString` retrieve your values as Float values and the use [`FloatToStrF`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/Seattle/en/System.SysUtils.FloatToStrF). E.g.

```
memo1.Lines.Add(FloatToStrF(frmMain.Query2.FieldByName('mass').AsFloat, ffNumber, 15, 2));
```

Answer (score 3):

I like [Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/System.SysUtils.Format).

```
Format('%.2n', [frmMain.Query2.FieldByName('mass').AsFloat]);
```